# denseness of tridiagonal positive semidefinitness in tridiagonal positive definiteness

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I know that pd (positive definite) matrices are dense in psd matrices. Let $A$ be TPSD (tridiagonal positive semi definite) with all entries positive. Does there exist a sequence of TPD matrices with all entries positive, which converge to $A$ ? Any small tips or suggestion is really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ tridiagonal positive semi definite (there is a mistake in your post) with all entries positive. Then $B_k=A+\dfrac{1}{k}I_n$ is tridiagonal positive definite with all entries positive (for every positive integer $k$). Moreover $B_k$ tends to $A$ when $k$ tends to $\infty$.